# Couldn't update to python 3.5 using the conda package by anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, centos7

I just updated my anaconda package using

```
conda update --prefix /home/srinath/anaconda3 anaconda
```

It updated my package to latest anaconda 2.4

When I enter this in my terminal

```
python --version
```

I got the result as

```
Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Why I am not getting 3.5 ? Anaconda 2.4 includes 3.5 , that's what I read in the  [blog](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/python-35-support-anaconda)
Please help me I want to try new features of 3.5 and use it for mainstream development

I am using centos 7 . Is this issue with my OS ?

Comment: Do you have python3.5 added to your path?

Comment: Anaconda package adds its bin to the path. So all the packages under `anaconda3/bin` are available. and I ls into the path and saw no python3.5 package is available

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command:

```
conda update --prefix /home/srinath/anaconda3 anaconda
```

Will not update Python 3.4.3 (your current version) to Python 3.5. To get python 3.5, you can either:

Upgrade your current version of Python to 3.5. Run the following command:

```
conda install python=3.5
```

Or create a new environment with Python 3.5. Run the following command:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

See [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#create-a-python-3-5-environment) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. Further I researched and found that I can activate the particular environment by
`source activate py35` 
thank you